# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void scala.util.matching.Regex.<init>(java.lang.String, scala.collection.Seq)'

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

This error occurs when I try to read .xlsx file as a DataFrame in csv format. Can anyone please help me what is the issue here and how to resolve it ? Below is the code I used,

```
package Sample

import org.apache.spark.sql{SparkSession, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

Object Read extends App {

val conf = new SparkConf()
.setAppName("Excel to DataFrame")
.setMaster("local[*]")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")


val spark = SparkSession.builder()
.appName("Excel to DataFrame")
.config("spark.master","local")
.getOrCreate()

val inputDF = spark.read
.format("csv")
.option("inferSchema","true")
.option("path","G:\\Sample Input.xlsx")
.load()

inputDF.show()
```

}

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the exception please?

Comment: Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void scala.util.matching.Regex.<init>(java.lang.String, scala.collection.Seq)'
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r(StringLike.scala:284)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r$(StringLike.scala:284)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:33)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r(StringLike.scala:273)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.r$(StringLike.scala:273)
at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:33)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.<init>(Utils.scala:104)

Comment: NoSuchMethodError usually means that there's a problem with the versions of some dependencies in your classpath. Maybe you are mixing Scala versions?

Comment: Hi Ibilger, Thanks for the comment. I will check that one too.

Comment: I'm getting the same error even if I tried to read a json file as DF.

Comment: Hi Ibilger, I checked the scala versions from previous project where it worked. Both  are same.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have encountered is that the scala version is not compatible with the spark you install in your operating system. So you need to reconfigure the scala version of the IDE you use, I will explain to you the solution in IntelliJ IDEA, First, go to **File -> Project Structure -> Global Libraries** and then click on **New Global Library (Alt+Insert)** and then Select **Scala SDK** Then a new window will be popup to you like this :
[New Global Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPjhr.png)
the scala version you see is the one that causes the problem to you, it needs to be suitable with the scala you install for spark so just go to the terminal and type **spark-shell** in the terminal you will see the version of scala you use in Spark :

[saprk-shell here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFGOd.png)
back to the **New Global Library** Window and click **Download** Select the version you have seen in the spark-shell and click **OK**. After that refresh Edit the dependency in pom.xml and refresh the project and the problem will be solved.